# win32 DialogBox() and MAKEINTRESOURCE(): how to modify the app's ui?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, device, joystick

I'm working on my project which is trying to control a camera by using a Joystick, 
and I found this sample code:

http://ukgtut.googlecode.com/svn-history/r53/trunk/irrlicht/src/proto_carace/Joystick.cpp

This app has its own ui which isn't fit to my project, the ui seems to be created by MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_JOYST_IMM ), I want to modify but don't know how to do.

Should I change the variable in MAKEINTRESOURCE() to modify the ui?
How can I build my own ui?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code you found is an example code that came with the DirectX SDK. You can download a more recent version of the full code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DirectInput-Samples-8ac6f5e3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  resource editor (or even a text editor) to modify the dialog template in the resource file.